# test class code coverage only 62% .how to increase coverage for this test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
trigger QuoteSyncTrigger on Quote (after insert, after update) {
    if (TriggerStopper.stopQuote) return;

    TriggerStopper.stopQuote = true;    

    Set<String> quoteFields = QuoteSyncUtil.getQuoteFields();
    List<String> oppFields = QuoteSyncUtil.getOppFields();

    String quote_fields = QuoteSyncUtil.getQuoteFieldsString();

    String opp_fields = QuoteSyncUtil.getOppFieldsString();

    Map<Id, Id> startSyncQuoteMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
    String quoteIds = '';
    for (Quote quote : trigger.new) {
        if (quote.isSyncing && !trigger.oldMap.get(quote.Id).isSyncing) {
            startSyncQuoteMap.put(quote.Id, quote.OpportunityId);
        }

        if (quoteIds != '') quoteIds += ', ';
        quoteIds += '\'' + quote.Id + '\'';
    }

    String quoteQuery = 'select Id, OpportunityId, isSyncing' + quote_fields + ' from Quote where Id in (' + quoteIds + ')';
    //System.debug(quoteQuery);     

    List<Quote> quotes = Database.query(quoteQuery);

    String oppIds = '';    
    Map<Id, Quote> quoteMap = new Map<Id, Quote>();

    for (Quote quote : quotes) {
        if (trigger.isInsert || (trigger.isUpdate && quote.isSyncing)) {
            quoteMap.put(quote.OpportunityId, quote);
            if (oppIds != '') oppIds += ', ';
            oppIds += '\'' + quote.opportunityId + '\'';            
        }
    }

    if (oppIds != '') {
        String oppQuery = 'select Id, HasOpportunityLineItem' + opp_fields + ' from Opportunity where Id in (' + oppIds + ')';
        //System.debug(oppQuery);     

        List<Opportunity> opps = Database.query(oppQuery);
        List<Opportunity> updateOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
        List<Quote> updateQuotes = new List<Quote>();        

        for (Opportunity opp : opps) {
            Quote quote = quoteMap.get(opp.Id);

            // store the new quote Id if corresponding opportunity has line items
            if (trigger.isInsert && opp.HasOpportunityLineItem) {
                QuoteSyncUtil.addNewQuoteId(quote.Id);
            }

            boolean hasChange = false;
            for (String quoteField : quoteFields) {
                String oppField = QuoteSyncUtil.getQuoteFieldMapTo(quoteField);
                Object oppValue = opp.get(oppField);
                Object quoteValue = quote.get(quoteField);
                if (oppValue != quoteValue) {                   
                    if (trigger.isInsert && (quoteValue == null || (quoteValue instanceof Boolean && !Boolean.valueOf(quoteValue)))) {
                        quote.put(quoteField, oppValue);
                        hasChange = true;                          
                    } else if (trigger.isUpdate) {
                        if (quoteValue == null) opp.put(oppField, null);
                        else opp.put(oppField, quoteValue);
                        hasChange = true;                          
                    }                    
                }                     
            }    
            if (hasChange) {
                if (trigger.isInsert) { 
                    updateQuotes.add(quote);
                } else if (trigger.isUpdate) {
                    updateOpps.add(opp);                
                }               
            }                                  
        } 

        if (trigger.isInsert) {
            Database.update(updateQuotes);
        } else if (trigger.isUpdate) {
            TriggerStopper.stopOpp = true;            
            Database.update(updateOpps);
            TriggerStopper.stopOpp = false;              
        }    
    }

    TriggerStopper.stopQuote = false; 
}
```

Test class

```
@istest
public class TestQuoteSyncTrigger {
    static Testmethod void TestQuoteSyncTrigger(){

        Account a = new Account(name='Test Account', billingStreet='Test', billingCity='Test', billingState='Test', billingCountry='Test');
        insert a;

        Opportunity o = new Opportunity();    
        o.Accountid = a.id;
        o.Name = 'test';
        o.StageName = 'Prospecting';
        o.CloseDate = date.today();
        o.Type = 'New Client';
        o.NextStep = 'Test';
        o.LeadSource = 'Business Development';
        insert o;

        Quote Q = new Quote();
        q.OpportunityId = o.id;
        q.Name = 'test';
        insert q;

        Quote Q1 = new Quote();
        Q1.id=q.id;
        q.Name = 'test1';
        update q;




    }
}
```

this part is not cover in test class

```
 for (String quoteField : quoteFields) {
                String oppField = QuoteSyncUtil.getQuoteFieldMapTo(quoteField);
                Object oppValue = opp.get(oppField);
                Object quoteValue = quote.get(quoteField);
                if (oppValue != quoteValue) {                   
                    if (trigger.isInsert && (quoteValue == null || (quoteValue instanceof Boolean && !Boolean.valueOf(quoteValue)))) {
                        quote.put(quoteField, oppValue);
                        hasChange = true;
```

Comment: Your test is not testing anything. It is simply causing code to execute. How do you know your code is doing what it is supposed to do according to the requirements?

Comment: As @Eric has said the test code is not really doing anything of benefit, you should be using an assert to make sure that when you are inserting your records the appropriate triggers and code are performing the actions that you are expecting.